# How do I setup a fallback for Webpack require?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hooks, state, requirejs

Webpack's require is being used to dynamically load images based on the state of the page.

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9xpQ.png)

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './target.png'
at webpackContextResolve (.png$:82:1)
at webpackContext (.png$:77:1)
```

This file does not exist as I have yet to create it, I want to be able to set a fallback src for a default image.

In the future I am planning to store images on the server instead of in code.

Before I do this I want to ensure everything still loads if the data of the server has not been populated yet by having fallback images stored in code.

[Code, onError is not catching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a236l.png)

```
<img className='absolute left-24 h-14 mt-2' src={require(`../Images/${this.state.activeItem.gadget}.png`)} onError={this.replaceImage} alt="gadget"></img>
```

[replaceImage to change src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbECR.png)

```
replaceImage = (error) => {
    error.target.src = fallbackimg; 
  }
```

fallbackimg is being imported at the top of the file:

> import fallbackimg from '../Images/Gadget.png';

How do I catch the uncaught error and change the src so I don't get a cannot find module error?